# Getting Calendar weekday symbols consisting of no more than two letters

Tags: ios, swift, string, calendar

I need to get weekday symbols but in their shortest format (two letters). I use `Calendar`'s `shortStandaloneWeekdaySymbols` property, however this returns days of week with three letters:

```
Calendar.current.shortStandaloneWeekdaySymbols
```

And the result:

```
["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
```

I would like to get something like this (for English):

```
["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"]
```

It is possible to remove the last character by hand, via `String`'s `removeLast()` method, however, I think, for some locales the result would be wrong.

So, is there a way to return two-letter weekday symbols from `Calendar`.

Comment: There is `veryShortStandaloneWeekdaySymbols` but in most cases those are one letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Calendar` does not provide built-in properties for getting the two-letter abbreviation for weekday names. However, the Unicode standard for date formatting does provide what you need. The format `EEEEEE` gives a two-letter weekday name and `cccccc` gives a two-letter standalone weekday name.

Here's a `Calendar` extension that gives you these values:

```
extension Calendar {
    var shorterWeekdaySymbols: [String] {
        return symbolsFor("EEEEEE")
    }

    var shorterStandaloneWeekdaySymbols: [String] {
        return symbolsFor("cccccc")
    }

    private func symbolsFor(_ format: String) -> [String] {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.locale = self.locale
        df.calendar = self
        df.dateFormat = format
        let weekdays = self.range(of: .weekday, in: .year, for: Date())!
        return weekdays.map {
            let date = self.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: DateComponents(weekday: $0), matchingPolicy: .strict)!
            return df.string(from: date)
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
print(Calendar.current.shorterWeekdaySymbols)
print(Calendar.current.shorterStandaloneWeekdaySymbols)
```

And an example for Spain:

```
var calES = Calendar.current
calES.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_ES")
print(calES.shorterWeekdaySymbols)
print(calES.shorterStandaloneWeekdaySymbols)
```

This has been tested with every locale for every calendar and none of the force-unwraps caused an issue.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer, although the `locale` property of `Calendar` is `get-only`, no? Also, could you explain the difference between two-letter weekday names and the standalone ones? I mean, is any one of them preferable over the other?

Comment: No, the `locale` property of `Calendar` is not read-only. The code in my answer works as-is. And from the documentation for `Calendar standaloneWeekdaySymbols`: "*Stand-alone properties are for use in places like calendar headers. Non-stand-alone properties are for use in context (for example, “Saturday, November 12th”)."*.

Comment: @rmaddy This returns the symbols starting from the wrong day if the calendar is manually set to certain time zones. Adding `df.timeZone = self.timeZone` fixed it for me.

Comment: @jjoelson The array should always start on Sunday no matter the calendar/timezone.

Comment: Right, but if you pick a calendar (`var calendar = Locale(identifier: "en_US").calendar`), and loop through `TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers` and set `calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZoneIdentifier)!` for each one, certain time zones result in weekdays that start with Saturday.